# Keeping users in sync with each other in an social network app?

Tags: ios, node.js, social-networking

I am wondering about what the best way to keep users in sync with each other in a social network is. The concerned stack is an iOS app with a NodeJS backend. Let me give you an example:

Say X and Y are friends on a social network. Y's posts appear in X's feed, and as such, Y is cached somewhere on the X's phone. This morning, Y decided to change profile pictures however. Everything is well, the new picture is uploaded to the server, but how do we go about letting X know about the change of profile picture?

**My possible solution:** Create a route `/<UID>/updates` that contains a stack of "cookies" which lets the user know what and who changed since the last time they made a GET request to the route.

This seems elegant enough, but what worries me is what happens on the client side (am I supposed to make a GET request every 2 minutes during my app's uptime?). Are there any other solutions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution is indeed to poll the server, but that's not very elegant. A better way is to make use of [websockets](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSockets_API):

> **WebSockets** is an advanced technology that makes it possible to open an interactive communication session between the user's browser and a server. With this API, you can send messages to a server and receive event-driven responses without having to poll the server for a reply.

They are a 2-way connection between client and server, allowing the server to notify the client of any changes. This is the underlying technology used in the Meteor framework for example.

Take a look at [this blogpost](http://divcode.blogspot.be/2012/12/nodejs-web-sockets-and-ios.html) for an example of how to use websockets between an iOS client and a NodeJS backend. They make use of the open source [SocketRocket](https://github.com/square/SocketRocket) iOS library.